# Create a new card for every item in a list

Tags: flutter

How can I create a new Card for every item in the crossSection list?

```
ListView(
          children: dummyCategories
              .map(
                (measurementData) => new DataCard(
                  measurementData.crossSections[0].id,
                  measurementData.crossSections[0].depth,
                  measurementData.crossSections[0].waterVelocities,
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
```

Comment: Use a ListView.builder it's more efficient. Just pass the DataCard widget in the builder function. Also no need to use new keyword in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list.generate( ... ) Instead of [ ] of children

And customize it for what you need